# capacitor unit is not specified

Tags: capacitor, units

I am currently working on a circuit but I can't figure out the non-polarized capacitor values, since some of them are not clearly specified as unit magnitude.

Some of them are: 100, 500, 180, 5.6, 56, 220.

What should I use; pF, nF, uF, mF, F?

[image: schematic of the circuit]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Some of them are: 100, 500, 180, 5.6, 56, 220. What should i use; pF,
> nF, uF, mF, F?*

All the ones that I can see should be in pico farads: -

[image]