# Schematic capacitor values without units

Tags: capacitor

I am currently trying to use AS3350 Dual Voltage Controlled State Variable Filter IC.  I was reading the [datasheet](https://www.ericasynths.lv/media/AS3350.pdf), but could not find some information.  I wonder if there was a more complete datasheet for this device?

[image]

My question right now is about CBP and CLP capacitors, which are stated to be 0,02.  What does this mean? 0.02 F, 0.02 uF, 0.02 pF?

Edit: For anybody searching this in the future, I have just tested it out with 20 nF (0.02 uF) and it worked great

Comment: Suggest merge with: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/544836/capacitor-unit-is-not-specified and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/661395/no-units-in-onsemi-datasheet-for-capacitor-what-is-the-default-unit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are microfarads.

0.02pF as a manufactured value is feasible only inside ICs, pretty much. 0.02F is 20,000μF - that would be a bit large in a filter like that. 0.02mF would be 20μF - not unheard of in this application, but that would be a very unusual choice of units - never saw these being the implied default. Those aren't nF either.

There are pF used on some capacitors: they mention pF explicitly on those.

Answer (score 4):

Evaluating 0.02F as to high for an Op-Amp to be stable (assumption, see VLPH1 Pin) and pF beeing denoted on other parts, i would go with 0.02uF